# Preparing for the next C++ standard

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

The spate of questions regarding `BOOST_FOREACH` prompts me to ask users of the Boost library what (if anything) they are doing to prepare their code for portability to the proposed new C++ standard (aka C++0x). For example, do you write code like this if you use `shared_ptr`:

```
#ifdef CPPOX
#include <memory>
#else
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#endif
```

There is also the namespace issue - in the future, `shared_ptr` will be part of the `std`, namespace - how do you deal with that?

I'm interested in these questions because I've decided to bite the bullet and start learning boost seriously, and I'd like to use best practices in my code.

**Not exactly a flood of answers - does this mean it's a non-issue? Anyway, thanks to those that replied; I'm accepting jalfs answer because I like being advised to do nothing!**

Comment: You mean C++09 right? It's got to come out in 8 months :)

Comment: @Robert: You mean, it's so far scheduled to come out in 8 months. It's nowhere near final. But yes, I think a lot of people would be disappointed if they don't make their 09 deadline. (By the way, I'm really starting to like the name c++0x. Couldn't they just stick with that? ;)

Comment: Well I think they should call it C++1x and give up on 0x, there is too much work left, and the current state is a mess, but if they aren't moving the deadline it's gotta come out in 8 months :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simple answer is "do nothing". Boost is not going to remove the libraries that got adopted into 0x. So boost::shared_ptr will still exist. So you don't need to do anything to maintain portability.

Of course, once 0x is here, a lot of code can be simplified, cleaned up and optimized, but since it's not yet here, that work can't really begin. All you can do is make sure your code will still compile when 0x hits... and it should, just like that. Boost isn't going to delete half their libraries. (I'm not guessing. They've stated this on their mailing list before)

(and if you want to switch to the standard shared_ptr, I'd say it's probably easier to just do a simple search/replace when the time comes. Replace `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` with `#include <memory>`, and `boost::shared_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr`)

Or of course, you can just decide on the project that you're going to keep using Boost's `shared_ptr`. Just because it's been added to the standard library doesn't mean you *have* to use it, after all.

Comment: Do-nothing is of course an attractive option, but viable? I wouldn't want to end up with two shared_ptr implementations in my code base - a potential debugging and support nightmare.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: You are hinting at namespace collision. This can be avoided.

Comment: Check my edit. I think the simplest way to switch implementations is a simple search/replace, once you upgrade to 0x. Until then, I'd avoid the extra clutter of #ifdefs and supporting both.

Comment: @jalf: +1. I agree :) And I have a feeling a lot of people are going to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will need to be done because of namespaces.  If you want to use the boost implementation you will still use the boost namesapce.

I don't think they would venture into breaking compatibility in such a big way with a previous version.

See my previous similar question here: [what will happen with the overlapping portion of boost once C++0x becomes mainstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405175/what-will-happen-with-the-overlapping-portion-of-boost-once-c0x-becomes-mainstr)

But of course if you do using namespace a lot in your code you may have some overlapping definitions.  You'll have to go back to specifying the namespace explicitly on each use.

Comment: Well either way the code won't compile so it won't be any problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use shared parts between C++0x and Boost is to use the Boost.TR1, i.e; the implementation if the Technical Report already accepted. Boost.TR1 will use the implementation provided by the compiler when it is available, and the provided by Boost otherwise. This was the main goal of Boost.TR1

"The TR1 library provides an implementation of the C++ Technical Report on Standard Library Extensions. This library does not itself implement the TR1 components, rather it's a thin wrapper that will include your standard library's TR1 implementation (if it has one), otherwise it will include the Boost Library equivalents, and import them into namespace std::tr1. "

Answer (score 1):

No we don't, as of yet, given the facts that:

- support for C++0x is not yet upto the mark across the various platforms (we need) and
- that it is *yet* to be declared a standard officially

But yes, we do use Boost as and when required (but of course, only after a release has gone through a sanitation phase do we use it) just like any other third party library that we use. Also, we use the source form on a as-needed basis.

There is however an effort towards more stringent adoption of the driving principles in product design phase (e.g. move-ctor etc).

There is definitely going to be some work when C++0x gets standardised; but that will also require us to move on to some of newer compilers (vc10?) and moving on to a new compiler is always *a task* in it's own.

Answer (score 1):

You may actually always prefer using the Boost version for a long time. Especially if you need to compile on multiple platforms.

The Boost libraries are ported and tested on multiple platforms and behave the same there (most of the time.)

The first vendor implementations of the new C++ libraries may still contain minor bugs and performance differences just like it was such a mess when STL and the std namespace were added.