# Portable way to use shared_ptr in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-ptr, tr1

GCC 4.1 uses the `<tr1/memory>` header and GCC 4.3 uses `<memory>` header, I need a portable way to use `shared_ptr` with GCC 4.3.2 and with GCC 4.2.1, is there any way to do that without checking GCC version macros or using external libraries like Boost ?

Comment: Maybe related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716904/preparing-for-the-next-c-standard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<tr1/memory>` will still work with gcc 4.3.  If you wan to support both versions, just use the `tr1` name.

Comment: Isn't that tr1 stuff meant to be removed somewhen? I thought it was something temporary until the standard was really approved.

Comment: @jedhaan - I've always assumed that even if something `tr1` made it into the standard, it would still be available in the `tr1` include files and namespaces for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this solution, but you might be able to add tr1 to the list of include directories on the gcc command line (-I or -isystem)